# Obtener Array dentro de Json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo dos tablas en MySql una Blog y otra Carouser unidad por una foreing key.

¿Como puedo obtener un json como el que figuar al final? Un array dentro de un objeto. En PHP.

```
CREATE TABLE `Blog` (
  `blogId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `blogTitulo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `blogSubtitulo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `blogDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `blogText` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `blogImg` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Carouser` (
  `imgId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imgName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `blogId` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Carouser`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`imgId`),
  ADD KEY `blogId` (`blogId`);
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "blogId": "11",
    "blogTitulo": "TITULO",
    "blogSubtitulo": "SUB",
    "blogDate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "blogText": "TEXTO",
    "userId": "1",
    "blogImg": "imagen1.jpg",
    "carouserImg": {
        "0": "imgane2.jpg",
        "1": "imgane3.jpg",
        "2": "imgane4.jpg",
        "3": "imgane5.jpg"
      }
  }
]
```

Comment: Por lo que entendi queres imprimir in json atravez de PHP no?, primero deberias ordenar la informacion en php en un array y luego con la funcion json_encode($array); es la que va a convertir todo en formato json

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer una consulta a la tabla blog, almacenar eso en un arreglo y luego una consulta a la tabla Carouser y hacer iteraciones para construir el arreglo, pero si las tablas tienen muchos datos, podrias hacer un query a la tabla Carouser por cada ítem de blog de la primera consulta a Blog, te dejo el pseudocodigo de esto ultimo.

```
array_blogs = new Array

blogs = Blog.execute_query("select * from BLOG")

blogs.each_one do |blog|
  item_blog = new Array

  item_blog["blogId"] = blog["blogId"]
  .
  .
  . 

  carousers = Carouser.execute_query("select * from CAROUSER where blog_id = " + blog.id)

  item_blog["carouserImg"] = carousers

  blogs.append(item_blog)

end

return json_encode(array_blogs)
```

Comment: Eso no parece muy php que digamos... No?